# Split string that has only letters

Tags: java

Is there any simple way to split sorted string that has **only letters**(no spaces).

For example if I have this string:

```
  string str ="aaasssdeettyy";
```

I need to split this string to sub strings:

```
string res = "aaa";
string res = "sss";
string res = "d";
string res = "ee";
string res = "tt";
string res = "yy";
```

Is there any way to implement it using split() command and regex expression?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: `\1` matches the same text as matched by the first group `(.)`

```
Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+");
Matcher matcher = compile.matcher("aaabbbcdddee");
while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```